# RxJS: How to combine multiple nested observables with buffer

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rename, rxjs5

Warning: RxJS newb here.

Here is my challenge:

1. When an `onUnlink$` observable emits...
2. Immediately start capturing values from an `onAdd$` observable, for a maximum of 1 second (I'll call this partition `onAddBuffer$`).
3. Query a database (creating a `doc$` observable) to fetch a model we'll use to match against one of the `onAdd$` values
4. If one of the values from the `onAddBuffer$` observable matches the `doc$` value, do not emit
5. If none of the values from the `onAddBuffer$` observable matches the `doc$` value, or if the `onAddBuffer$` observable never emits, emit the `doc$` value

This was my best guess:

```js
// for starters, concatMap doesn't seem right -- I want a whole new stream
const docsToRemove$ = onUnlink$.concatMap( unlinkValue => {

  const doc$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise( db.File.findOne({ unlinkValue }) )

  const onAddBuffer$ = onAdd$
    .buffer( doc$ ) // capture events while fetching from db -- not sure about this
    .takeUntil( Rx.Observable.timer(1000) );

  // if there is a match, emit nothing. otherwise wait 1 second and emit doc
  return doc$.switchMap( doc =>
    Rx.Observable.race( 
      onAddBuffer$.single( added => doc.attr === added.attr ).mapTo( Rx.Observable.empty() ),
      Rx.Observable.timer( 1000 ).mapTo( doc )
    )
  );
});

docsToRemove$.subscribe( doc => {
  // should only ever be invoked (with doc -- the doc$ value) 1 second
  // after `onUnlink$` emits, when there are no matching `onAdd$`
  // values within that 1 second window.
})
```

This always emits `EmptyObservable`. Maybe it's because `single` appears to emit `undefined` when there is no match, and I'm expecting it not to emit at all when there is no match? The same thing happens with `find`.

If I change `single` to `filter`, nothing ever emits.

FYI: This is a rename scenario with file system events -- if an `add` event follows within 1 second of an `unlink` event and the emitted file hashes match, do nothing because it's a `rename`. Otherwise it's a true `unlink` and it should emit the database doc to be removed.

Comment: It sounds like you are building a pretty nasty race condition here. Timeouts aren't usually a good way to deal with this — if things take longer once for whatever reason, you lose data.

Comment: yes there is definitely potential for a race condition here. it may ultimately defeat this approach. but it seemed like a good opportunity for learning rxjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my guess how you could do this:

```
onUnlink$.concatMap(unlinkValue => {
  const doc$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(db.File.findOne({ unlinkValue })).share();
  const bufferDuration$ = Rx.Observable.race(Rx.Observable.timer(1000), doc$);
  const onAddBuffer$ = onAdd$.buffer(bufferDuration$);

  return Observable.forkJoin(onAddBuffer$, doc$)
    .map(([buffer, docResponse]) => { /* whatever logic you need here */ });
});
```

The `single()` operator is a little tricky because it emits the item that matches the predicate function only **after the source Observable completes** (or emits an error when there're two items or no matching items).

The `race()` is tricky as well. If one of the source Observables completes and doesn't emit any value `race()` **will just complete and not emit anything**. I reported this some time ago and this is the correct behavior, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2641.
I guess this is what went wrong in your code.

Also note that `.mapTo(Rx.Observable.empty())` will map each value into an instance of Observable. If you wanted to ignore all values you can use `filter(() => false)` or the `ignoreElements()` operator.